# X and Y are independent? $f(x,y) = \frac{e^{-y}\:e^{-\frac{x}{y}}}{y}$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let

$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{e^{-y}\:e^{-\frac{x}{y}}}{y}$$

It's okay to do this:

$$f_Y(y) = e^{-y}, y > 0 $$

This was achieved by solving:

$$f_Y(y) =\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-y}\:e^{-\frac{x}{y}}}{y} dx$$

and

$$f_X(x) = \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{y}}}{y}, x>0 $$

Obtained by:

$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = e^{-y} \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{y}}}{y}$$

$$f_X(x) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{y}}}{y} dx = 1 $$

Therefore is density.

This guarantees independence?

Comment: $f_X(x)$ cannot depend on $y$.  In fact, the variables are not independent.

Comment: Note that your expression for $f_X(x)$ also depends on variable  $y$ hence makes no sense at all.

Comment: @drhab - it may make some sort of sense as a conditional likelihood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if the variables are independent then we must have $f_{X,Y} (x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ for some $g$ and $h$. By first putting $y=x$ and writing $g$ in terms of $h$ try to get a contradiction.